Energy conservation and kinetic energy calculation of ions
I read in paper (link to the paper) about leak-out spectroscopy (which is action spectroscopy with ion trap), and in this paper they do a calculated of new kinetic energy of the ion.
the description of the situation is that vibrational excited ion collusion with inert molecule and then the vibrational energy of the excited ion return to translation energy of the ion, so the ion have new kinetic energy.
now is the question:
they calculate the new kinetic energy of the ion as:
$$E_K=\dfrac{m_{inert}}{m_{inert}+m_{ion}}\cdot E_{vib} $$
when:
$m_{inert}$ is the mass of the inert gas
$m_{ion}$ is the mass of the ion
$E_{vib}$ is the energy of the vibrational excitation
and I don't understand why. I try to do equations of energy conservation and momentum conservation, but it's not work. I get two equations and four unknown. I try to suggested that the inert gas doesn't change energy with the ion but is also not work.
how can I get this term of kinetic energy?
